# Keeping multiple figures open with matplotlib after script is executed

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, window, figure

I have a question regarding windows/figures in matplotlib. I'm not sure if this is possible, but would like to know if it is. 
Basically when I run my whole script, at the end a graph is plotted using matplotlib. In order to produce a new graph after running my script again I have to close that graph window.

Is there a way of keeping open the figure without closing it?

Let me give an example:

I would plot graph x by running my script.

I would then like to keep this graph on my screen, make a change to my script, plot the graph again so you may see the old graph and the new graph. Therefore n number of graphs may be visible.

Please note that I do NOT want to plot a new figure within my script. I simply would like to be able to see the graph, make a change and see the new graph WITHOUT having to save the graph.

**EDIT**:

This is the plotting secion of my code:

```
def plot_data(atb_mat_2, sd_index, sd_grad):#, rtsd):#, sd_index, sd_grad):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig, (ax0, ax1, ax4, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=5, figsize=(15,10), num='Current Relative Method'+'  ' + path)
    ax0.plot(atb_mat_2)
    ax0.set_title('Relative Track',fontsize=11)
    ax0.set_ylim([-10,10])
    if len(sd_index)!=0:
        if len(sd_index)>1:
            for i in range(1, len(sd_index)):
                if sd_grad[i]==1:
                    ax0.axvspan(sd_index[i-1],sd_index[i], edgecolor='r', lw=None, alpha=0.1)
    ax1.plot(rtsd)
    ax1.set_title('RT Standard Deviation',fontsize=11)
    ax1.set_ylim([0,250])
    ax4.plot(abs_track_data)
    ax4.set_title('Absolute Track',fontsize=11)
    ax4.set_ylim([3000,5000])
    ax2.plot(splitpo)
    ax2.set_title('Track Split',fontsize=11)
    ax2.set_ylim([0,20])
    ax3.plot(ts)
    ax3.set_title('TS Standard Deviation',fontsize=11)
    ax3.set_ylim([0,100])

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Thanks alot of any advice and sorry if this answer is obvious as I'm fairly new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `ipython`.

1. Write your script and save it as (for example) `test.py`. The script should create a figure, do the plotting and show the plot:

   ```py
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

   fig = plt.figure()
   x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
   y = np.sin(x)
   plt.plot(x, y)
   plt.show()
   ```
2. Start the `ipython` console using:

   ```
   ipython --pylab=qt
   ```

   Or whatever backend you want to use.
3. In the `ipython` shell type:

   ```
   %run /path/to/the/test.py
   ```

   This will create a figure, and show the plot.
4. After that change your script. For example change the 5th line to:

   ```
   x = np.linspace(-0, 2, 100)
   ```
5. Repeat the `%run` command in the `ipython` shell:

   ```
   %run /path/to/the/test.py
   ```

   Another figure will pop up with the new plot. Old figure will be also visible (this won't remove it or replace it).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and when I implement what you say it works for the test script. However it does not work with my script. Please see my edit. Is it due to not having the line `fig = plt.figure()`?

Comment: @AshleighClayton First you have an extra figure, you should remove the line `fig = plt.figure()`. But that is not the bug, the bug is that you specified the `num` of the figure, so it will reuse the figure since the figure with that `num` already exists. Just remove the `num` parameter of the `subplots` function and everything will work ok.

Comment: Thanks alot @ViktorKerkez. Solved the problem